# Serve apple-app-site-association with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ios-universal-links, webpack-file-loader

I'm new to webpack and I can't seem to find a way to serve the Apple Universal Links file under / using webpack.

Could you please advise how to get /apple-app-site-association working?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to serve apple-app-site-association through webpack you could add loader
and add import for this file in main.js for example

```
{
  test: /apple-app-site-association/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: [
  {
    loader:'file-loader', 
    options: {
      name: '/[name]',
    }
  }]
}
```